# Integration in React with Ruby on Rails.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs

I was following the instructions from a tutorial about integrating React with Ruby on Rails. I installed webpack  'webpacker', 'haml' and 'ransack'. All my backend code is working right now.

I created a view to point to my jsx files. On a Hello World attempt, the jsx its correctly rendered. My problem is after that.

I created a JobOffers.jsx file. So, on my dashboard file i pointed to this other one.

This is my dashboard.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import JobOffers from './JobOffers'


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <JobOffers/>
  )
})
```

And this is my JobOffer.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class JobOffers extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      term: '',
      autoCompleteResults: [],
      itemSelected: {},
      showItemSelected: false
    };

    $.getJSON('/search?q=' + this.state.term)
      .then(response => this.setState({ autoCompleteResults: response.items }))
  }

  getAutoCompleteResults(e){
    this.setState({
      term: e.target.value
    }, () => {
      $.getJSON('/search?q=' + this.state.term)
        .then(response => this.setState({ autoCompleteResults: response.items }))
    });
  }

  render(){
    let autoCompleteList = this.state.autoCompleteResults.map((response, index) => {
      return <div key={index}>
        <h2>{response.title}</h2>
        <p>{response.description }</p>
      </div>
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <input ref={ (input) => { this.searchBar = input } } value={ this.state.term } onChange={ this.getAutoCompleteResults.bind(this) } type='text' placeholder='Search...' />
        { autoCompleteList }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <JobOffers />,
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')),
  )
});

export default JobOffers;
```

When I go to the page, it renders for less then one second the right input, and then disappears. Anyone know what Im doing wrong here?

Comment: Move request from `constructor` to `componentDidMount`

Comment: Thanks Leo. It works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dashboard.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import JobOffers from './JobOffers'


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <JobOffers/>,
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')),
  )
})
```

JobOffers.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class JobOffers extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      term: '',
      autoCompleteResults: [],
      itemSelected: {},
      showItemSelected: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    $.getJSON('/search?q=' + this.state.term)
      .then(response => this.setState({ autoCompleteResults: response.items }))
  }

  getAutoCompleteResults(e){
    this.setState({
      term: e.target.value
    }, () => {
      $.getJSON('/search?q=' + this.state.term)
        .then(response => this.setState({ autoCompleteResults: response.items }))
    });
  }

  render(){
    let autoCompleteList = this.state.autoCompleteResults.map((response, index) => {
      return <div key={index}>
        <h2>{response.title}</h2>
        <p>{response.description }</p>
      </div>
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <input ref={ (input) => { this.searchBar = input } } value={ this.state.term } onChange={ this.getAutoCompleteResults.bind(this) } type='text' placeholder='Search...' />
        { autoCompleteList }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default JobOffers;
```